# How to change forms visibility in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have to change the visibility of the parent form as I move to the next form so the the previous form is not visible.

Comment: @PoulBak Not helping. I want the parent form to disappear i.e. set not visible as I can not close the parent form

Comment: @PoulBak, did you write "This.Hide()" before calling the child form? Also you could set custom "Opacity" to make form semitransparent

Comment: @MovsarBekaev : Thanks, the "This.Hide()" worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This.Hide()
```

or

```
myForm.Visible = false;
```

If you need to close it then

```
myForm.Close()
```

Answer (score -1):

use 
this.Hide();
or 
Application.Exit()

Comment: Why on earth would `Application.Exit();` do?!

Comment: @VisualVincent :yes i don't want to close the application. But any want the problem is solved using the "This.Hide()".